# Is this the cardinality of $A$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

We have a cycic group $G$ of order $20$. We have the generator $a$ of $G$. We also have the subgroup $H=\langle a^8\rangle$ of $G$. Let $b$ be a quotient of $a$ in $G/H$. Let $A$ be the set of $j\in \{3,5,7,11,15,17\}$ such that $b^j=b$ in $G/H$. I want to determine the number of elements of $A$.

$$$$

I have done the following:

The order of $G$ is $20$ and the order of $H$ is $\frac{20}{(20,8)}=5$.

So $|G/H|=\frac{20}{5}=4$.

We have that $b^j=b\Rightarrow b^{j-1}=1$ in $G/H$. So the order of $G/H$ divides $j-1$, or not?

So $4\mid j-1$. This holds only for $j=5$ and $j=17$.

Therefore, $|A|=2$.

Is this correct?

Comment: This is correct. Be careful however about the terminology: $b$ is the *image* of $a$ in the quotient $G/H$ ; let $A$ be the *subset* of $\{ 3,5,7,11,15,17\}$ consisting of the elements $j$ such that [...]

Comment: Great!! Thank you!! :-) @Suzet

Comment: Also, just a precision: the fact that $b^{j-1}=1$ in $G/H$ implies that the order *of $b$* divides $j-1$. Then, one argues that the order of $b$ is the same as the order of $G/H$, that is $4$. Of course, this is obvious given that $b$ is a generator of $G/H$.